# read and write to console using vba

Tags: vba

Is there a way to read and write to command prompt console using VBA? 
Im currently using Shell.Run command but the problem is it cannot read the output of the console while Shell.Exec read the output but wait for the program to finish. 
I want an interactive communication between a third party program and vba through the use of command prompt console.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim vbtShell As New WshShell
    Dim appPath As String
    Dim errRet As Long
    Dim strOut As String

    'Set the directory of the application
    appPath = "C:\Users\MyPC\Documents"
    vbtShell.CurrentDirectory = appPath

    'Run the application
    errRet = vbtShell.Run("app.exe >C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Log.txt", 1, False)

    'Try to read to console
    ''When I try to read to Console there was no Output
    strOut = GetFileContent("C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Log.txt")

    'If reading to console is successful send another command to continue.
    ''I cannot send another console command because it opens another command prompt window.
    If strOut = "Press Any Key To Continue:" Then
        errRet = vbtShell.Run("cmd.exe /k y", 1, False)
    End If
    'Read Final Output of the Console Application
    ''No final Ouput was read because we was not able to send a key to continue the program.
    strOut = GetFileContent("C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Log.txt")
    MsgBox (strOut)
End Sub
Public Function GetFileContent(Name As String) As String
    Dim intUnit As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrGetFileContent
    intUnit = FreeFile
    Open Name For Input As intUnit
    GetFileContent = Input(LOF(intUnit), intUnit)

ErrGetFileContent:
    Close intUnit
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Can you give a more specific example?

Comment: For example, I have an application (app.exe) there is a specific line in this app that will tell the user to press any key to continue in the console, when this happens I will send again a command in the console to continue the program.

Comment: Here is the problem, I tried to run the app.exe in MSExcel VBA application, but I was not able to detect or read the output of the console, and I cannot send another command because when I do the shell.run command it opens another console window.

Comment: Hi, where is your current code? Please include that and [edit] it and information about what you want to see happen, and what is actually happening into the question.  We need to be able to try and reproduce this problem. Hence the requirement for [MCVE].

Comment: Hi QHarr, This is my code for this project. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

A more specific example would help.

The following for example both reads and writes to the command line from VBE:

```
Dim myDir As String: myDir = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testfolder"
Debug.Print CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /V /C cd " & myDir & " && (for /f ""eol=: delims="" %F in ('dir /b /od *.csv') do @set ""newest=%F"" ) && echo !newest!").StdOut.ReadAll
```

The above writes to the command line asking it to csv files in the specified folder and reads the file name of the file with the most recent modified date.